# Does CUrl create a session on an Http server

Tags: apache, http, session, cookies, curl

My question is not related to a specific programming language (Php or Java).

What I want to know is: do a `curl` request (`GET` or `POST`) to an `Http server` (say `Apache httpd`), create a session on this server?

And if so, does it use the same session for other `CUrl` requests?

Comment: curl can use cookies and hence create a session on the target server

Comment: But in case where we dont want to create a ` cookie session`, next requests will be session-agnostic ?

Comment: yes ofcourse. You can simply disable the cookies, or manually unset cookies(if the website mandates a certain cookies)

Answer (score 1):

It can create a request to create a session on a remote server. The remote server will still be then one to handle the creation of the session being requested by the curl.

Comment: But do the same `session` persist between different `CUrl` requests, by default? And if not, does it mean that if the `CUrl` command is asynchronous and that the same client is executing them at the same time, they will launch as if they started from different `clients`?